# Creating bar graphs with groups of data

Tags: java, graph

So I'm trying to create a bar graph that features three different bars for each entry, how many people took a test, how many failed, and how many passed, all together for each test.  My code looks like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < evolNumber; i++) {
    if (chosenReports[i] == 1) {
        reportAttemptSummary += '<td class="TableArea" style="width:20px" align="center" valign="bottom">' +
        attemptTotal[i] +
        '<div style="background:black;width:20px;height:' +
        (attemptTotal[i] * 4) +
        'px"> </div>'+
        '</td>' +
        '<td class="TableArea" style="width:20px" align="center" valign="bottom">' +attemptPass[i]+
        '<div style="background:green;width:20px;height:' +
        (attemptPass[i] * 4) +
        'px"> </div>' +
        '</td>' +
        '<td class="TableArea" style="width:20px" align="center" valign="bottom">' +
        attemptFail[i] +
        '<div style="background:red;width:20px;height:' +
        (attemptFail[i] * 4) +
        'px"> </div>' +
        '</td>';
    }
}
```

How do I get these three bars to have a single title under all three of them:

Comment: Have you looked at [`JFreeChart`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html)?

Answer (score 3):

Since you seem to be outputing a HTML table then its a matter of creating a row directly after the row with the bars. So If you mean to have a single title that spans across the 3 bars then:

```
  <tr>
     <td colspan="3">Your single title here</td>
  </tr>
```

will do the trick if you output it after the row with the bars.